# Is it required to add Firebase Analytics to build.gradle?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

I am following the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android) to add Firebase to my Flutter project. I want to use Firebase Analytics so I added it in pubspec.yaml

The package page for [Firebase Analytics](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics#-readme-tab-) does not mention anything about adding Analytics as a dependency in `android/app/build.gradle`

No such thing is mentioned in Firebase for Flutter page either which I linked earlier. Now when registering the app in Firebase Console, it asks to add implementation of Firebase Analytics in app level build.gradle

[image: Flutter Firebase Analytics]

So do I need to add it or not as it looks like only Firebase Console wants me to add it but couldn't find any mention of it on any official Flutter page.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question as well. Is seems obvious, that you should add the dependency on `com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics` to your project.

But… You actually don't need it.

It's easy to test! Just set up the Firebase Analytics like it is described in the docs:

1. `google-services.json`
2. `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` (and related things)
3. Configure multidex
4. `firebase_analytics: ^X.Y.Z` in `pubspec.yaml`

Don't add any Firebase dependencies to you `app/build.gradle`!

Now, enable the DebugView in Firebase Analytics: `adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app your.package`.

Run the app and send some events. Open the DebugView in Firebase Analytics console and you'll see them all!

Probably, all the magic happens in [the Google Services Gradle Plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin):

> The google-services plugin has two main functions:
>
> 1. Add dependencies for basic libraries required for the services you have enabled. …
>
>    You can see the result of this step by running `./gradlew :app:dependencies`.

So, the plugin seems to add them for you!

You could also check what dependencies will be autoconfigured, by running `./gradlew :projects` from your `android` dir. Mine is:

```
Root project 'android'
+--- Project ':app'
+--- Project ':firebase_analytics'
\--- Project ':firebase_core'
```

Now, after I add `firebase_auth` to my `pubspec.yml` and run `flutter pub get`, this command indeed lists one extra project:

```
Root project 'android'
+--- Project ':app'
+--- Project ':firebase_analytics'
+--- Project ':firebase_auth'
\--- Project ':firebase_core'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Google Analytics for Firebase SDK in your app and enabling analytics settings in the Firebase console is optional. It depends on what Firebase product you will be using. If Firebase suggests you add the Analytics SDK, it means that the Firebase product has integration with Analytics. See this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries) for your reference.

Comment: The page you have linked is for traditional Android and not for Flutter. In Flutter, there is a file called `pubspec.yaml` where we do add required dependencies.

Comment: Hi mate, the way of adding the dependencies is not the same, but same rule applies.

Comment: That is why I asked this question because if it was really required, it should have been mentioned on at least 1 Flutter page but even on the official Firebase Analytics for Flutter page, there is no mention for it. By the way, adding dependencies is exactly same in traditional android and flutter, Flutter has the same 2 build.grade files one in project, other in app level.

Comment: Understood. If you're looking for an offical documentation, then you can file a feature request to update the documentation. Cheers :D

Comment: In the setup page, step 4.4, there's a code sample there for analytics enabled and disabled. If analytics is required by default, they shouldn't add the disabled option at all.